# get array of inputs from http request - Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

First time doing this. I am having a tough time trying to complete this. Three days on this now. I transitioned the php Twilio/sdk over to Laravel and have successfully sent a text with Twilio's api to my phone. I am now figuring out how to receive the reply text.

(I tried the laravel packages for this and they only send the text, not receive the reply)
I am getting an error on my code.

```
Undefined index: From
```

If I move the header to my view I get a whoops error.

I also tried replacing the REQUEST with

```
$name = in_array(Input::get('name'), $people) ? Input::get('name') : 'default';
```

Here is my receiving function

```
public function getReceiveSMS() {
    // make an associative array of senders we know, indexed by phone number
$people = array(
    "1111111111"=>"Curious George",
    "1111111111"=>"Boots",
    "1111111111"=>"Virgil",
    "1111111111"=>"Stephen",
);

// if the sender is known, then greet them by name
// otherwise, consider them just another monkey
if(!$name = $people[$_REQUEST['From']]) {
    $name = "Monkey";
}

// now greet the sender
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

return View::make('account.sms.receive-sms');
}
}
```

Here is my view

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

<Response>
    <Message><?php echo $name ?>, thanks for the message!</Message>
</Response>


@stop
```

Comment: How do you send this request ? I mean what is the name of the input containing the phone number ? because here you are assuming this input's name is 'From' !

Comment: This is the controller you're expecting Twilio to call? I assume you're trying to test it in the browser. It expects a request parameter named `From` which you haven't supplied. Also it's very unlikely you should be extending layout.main, the `Response` element should be all you return.

Comment: Yes, I am using routes and this controller with a send function and a receive function. My goal is to test it in the browser and get it working. The extending layout.main is nothing more than a template for my whole app. It sounds like you are saying to drop the html and just keep it in the contoller and routes. The Twilio rep to told me "You would want to ensure your messaging URL returns XML, not HTML. Twilio isn't able to understand HTML." If that is the case then how and where would I render the receiving function and xml to get the reply.

Comment: The twilio rep also said To receive SMS you would need to configure the messaging URL for your Twilio phone number. The messaging url is https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/sms/reply/

Comment: @DaveMorrissey, how do I supply a from if I am just testing it in the browser. Do I need to create another form with the input type from similar to what I did on the sending text, and then just pass that to my route which grabs my controller?

Comment: Just add a From querystring parameter on the URL e.g. `?From=1111111111`. Your view should not extend `layout.main` because it will give you a load of HTML before and after the XML. Your view should just be the `<Response>` element, nothing else.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the querystring parameter. I just do not know how to call the url besides doing it directly and passing a variable. Here is what I did and now I get undefined $name error in my view. http://laravel.io/bin/zXXyW

Comment: The undefined name is fixed. I am seeing the xml, I just do not know how to simply communicate with Twilio to get the reply message back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Twilio's API, but it seems the error is just basic PHP, and you're being held back by the fact that Laravel is far less lenient than regular PHP, meaning undefined variables and indexes will halt processing just like a fatal error would.

If in fact the sender can be unknown, and when that does happen the `From` index won't ever be set, the following should prevent your code from triggering a `Notice`:

```
// if the sender is known, then greet them by name
// otherwise, consider them just another monkey
if(!isset($_REQUEST['From']) || !$name = $people[$_REQUEST['From']]) {
    $name = "Monkey";
}
```

As for your malformed XML, try this instead of a simple `View::make()`:

```
return Response::view('account.sms.receive-sms', compact('name'))->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Comment: I replaced your code with mine and still get a whoops error. Here is the link http://tinypic.com/r/124f1qw/8 I think something with the headers is throwing it off.

Comment: At least the undefined index error seems to be gone. Now you're getting a "opening and ending tag mismatch", which should mean a malformed XML. I don't think it has anything to do with the headers, but we'd need to see the rest of the code to help you further.

Comment: SMSController.php http://laravel.io/bin/lYY9W Routes http://laravel.io/bin/eyyqo send-sms view http://laravel.io/bin/M22Pl receive-sms viewhttp://laravel.io/bin/Y554V navigation to routes http://laravel.io/bin/GqqXa

Comment: Have you tried it without the comments at the start of the receive view? Also, try removing the header declaration from the XML view and see if you can get it to print in plain text, then run it through an XML validator. Finally, see edited answer for the right way to change headers on Laravel.

Comment: Thank you for the revision and help on this. I think that cleared up the header issue because I just have the response in the view now. But I am getting an undefined $name from the view.

Comment: Yes, we forgot to pass the `name` variable into the view. See the edited answer.

Comment: I can now see the xml page perfect. However, the reply is not being sent when I see the xml page. Am I passing the url correctly through the REQUEST.Here is the updated controller http://laravel.io/bin/ayydy

Comment: Your `getReceiveSMS` method isn't communicating with Twilio at all. Furthermore, you seem to be confusing the $_REQUEST array with the Request class and the possibility of dispatching a get request to fetch the demo XML. I'm afraid you'll have to keep studying Twilio's API, because my answer only patched up the Laravel errors, but there's a logic problem I can't help you with.

Comment: I will keep on studying it. Thank you though for helping me with the syntax errors.